# Access a key on a typescript interface

Tags: typescript, interface

I don't think this is possible, but given this:

**interface**

```
import {BrowserService} from "../services/browser/index";

export interface IPrimaryNavigation {
    opts:IPrimaryNavigationOpts;
}

export interface IPrimaryNavigationOpts {
    ...
    browserService:BrowserService;
    ...
}
```

**class:**

```
import {IPrimaryNavigation, IPrimaryNavigationOpts} from "./interface";

export class PrimaryNavigation implements IPrimaryNavigation {
   public opts:IPrimaryNavigationOpts;
   ...
   mounted():void {
        ...
        this.listenForBootstrap(this.opts.bsNav, this.opts.browserService);
    }
    listenForBootstrap(menuName:string,browserService:<???>):void {
                                                       ^^^ here is the problem - 
    // I want to do the equivalent of IPrimaryNavigationOpts.browserService but can't. 
    // I don't think I should have to import the IBrowserService explicitly.

    }
}
```

How do you get around this issue. I can't seem to find any examples online that deal with such an issue. I admit I am very new to all of this, so pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can re-export used stuff. So, inside of the **"./interface"** we can do *(check the last lines)*:

```
import {BrowserService} from "../services/browser/index";

export interface IPrimaryNavigation {
    opts:IPrimaryNavigationOpts;
}

export interface IPrimaryNavigationOpts {
    ...
    browserService:BrowserService;
    ...
}
// re-export used interface
export { BrowserService }
```

And now, we can import even that type

```
// we import the re-exported type
import {IPrimaryNavigation, IPrimaryNavigationOpts
        BrowserService } from "./interface";

export class PrimaryNavigation implements IPrimaryNavigation {
   public opts:IPrimaryNavigationOpts;
   ...
   mounted():void {
        ...
        this.listenForBootstrap(this.opts.bsNav, this.opts.browserService);
    }
    listenForBootstrap(menuName:string,browserService:BrowserService):void {
    //listenForBootstrap(menuName:string,browserService:<???>):void {
    //                                                   ^^^ here is the problem - 
    // I want to do the equivalent of IPrimaryNavigationOpts.browserService but can't. 
    // I don't think I should have to import the IBrowserService explicitly.

    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, this is the correct answer. When I tried @AlexG's approach of using typeof, Typescript still complained that it could not find `IPrimaryNavigationOpts` interface

Answer (score 0):

You can type it as: `browserService: typeof IPrimaryNavigationOpts.browserService`

Comment: `Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'IPrimaryNavigationOpts'.` This quite weird.